# Trim Wordpress Blogpost Title

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, title, posts

```
<h2 class="entry-title" itemprop="headline">
<a href="http://alzheimerscare.in/lorem-ipsum-is-simply-dummy-text-of-the-printing-and-typesetting-industry-lorem-ipsum-has-been-the-industrys/" title="Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry’s" rel="bookmark">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry’s</a>
</h2>
```

I want to trim wordpress blog post title to minimum 15 characters, there are many posts are there in the page and i want to trim the title using jquery or javascript to minimum 15 characters of each post. thank you.

Comment: By *trim wordpress blog post title to minimum 15* do you mean trim wordpress blog post title to **maximum** 15

Comment: yes to maximum 15  @Nico

Comment: ...and you really want to do that with jQuery and not PHP?

Comment: want to do that using Jquery. @mayersdesign

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the trick. It finds every title on the page, trims it to fifteen characters and adds "..." - Unless you are then doing some kind of "show/hide" effect or something  else, this would likely be better accomplished in php ;)

```
$(".entry-title a").each (function () {
  if ($(this).text().length > 15)
    $(this).text($(this).text().substring(0,15) + '...');
});
```